# Iconfont not displaying when CDN is enabled

Tags: 7, cdn

I am using the [Icon](https://www.drupal.org/project/icon) module to display iconfonts on my Drupal 7 site and they work fine until I enable the [CDN](https://www.drupal.org/project/cdn) module. Upon enabling the CDN module, the iconfonts are displayed as blank squares and the console displays the following error message:

> Font from origin `http://CDN_URL` has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin `http://SITE_URL` is therefore not allowed access.

The browsers tested are:

- Google Chrome Version 38.0.2114.2 dev (64-bit) - Iconfonts are blank squares
- Apple Safari Version 7.0.5 (9537.77.4) - Working fine
- Mozilla Firefox 32.0 - Iconfonts are squares with the \eXXX code

I have tried to add the following lines to the htaccess file in my root directory, but that did not work.

```
# Apache config
<FilesMatch ".(eot|ttf|otf|woff)">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So if it works in one browser then the problem is browser related. I googled a solution for firefox: [Firefox doesn't allow cross-domain fonts](http://red-team-design.com/firefox-doesnt-allow-cross-domain-fonts-by-default/). Try it and if it works I'm sure you will be able to find the solution for Chrome also.

Comment: I see that you have already tried that solution. But I am convinced that it should work. Is mod_headers installed properly on Apache?

Comment: To narrow it down further, why don't you inspect the headers in firefox to see if Apache modified it or not. If it has been modified, then you have some other issue. If it has not been modified then your Apache config needs looking at.